# Menu with the overflow:scroll - position selected element center

Tags: reactjs, css

I have the vertical navigation with the overflow: scroll, so on mobile, the menu items get hidden except for the ones that you scroll to.

On page refresh or if I select a different page the scroll starts in the beginning again.

What I want is the corresponding item to always be in the view if it matches the page.

Is there a way to center the selected item by using CSS? Like can I force the scroll to be at the point where the selected menu was located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, CSS alone will not do this. You need to use javascript to set the scroll position. I think you can get the scroll position of the element you want centered and then use that to scroll into the correct position.

Check out:

window.scroll() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

and

.scrollTo() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop